# Windows 7 wallpaper slideshow

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, slideshow

Is there any way to modify the current active theme and change only [Slideshow] section?

UPD: Particularly I'm interested to change RssFeed value of currect theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1. Right click on the Desktop and select `Personalize`
2. Select your theme and it will apply
3. Click on the Desktop Background option at the bottom
4. Make the changes as required and click `Save Changes`

The theme will now be marked as `Unsaved theme` and will retain all the selected theme's settings apart from that which you changed.

You can save this as a new theme if you wish

---

**EDIT: Further answer following comments discussion**

To add an RSS feed you will have to manually edit the .theme file

Customise your theme with everything else you want apart from the RSS

Save the theme

It will be located in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`

Open the .theme file in a text editor and update/add a `[Slideshow]` section as follows:

```
[Slideshow]
Interval=1800000
Shuffle=1
RssFeed=http://YourFeedURLHere
```

Save the changes then double-click on the .theme file to reload it into the `Personalize` settings.

Click on the `Download Attachments` button when prompted

Based on instructions in [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-a-bing-wallpaper-desktop-slideshow-in-windows-7/)

Comment: yea, but how do I set RSS feed when I edit background? It only allows me to browse for folders.

Comment: Your original question mentions nothing about RSS feeds...?!?

Comment: Oh just noticed that Sliedshow square brackets were stripped away from my original post, which was intended to explain what I want. sorry will update it now.

Comment: @Michael I've updated my answer with further info.

Comment: Perfect, but imagine I have some customized theme, just want to change [Slideshow] part. Creating new .theme file would overwrite my existing theme I suppose?

Comment: @Michael - I would guess that you can change the `DisplayName=` line in the `[Theme]` section to a new value and save as a new file name and it won't overwrite

Comment: @Michael - I just tried saving it with the same name and I get 2 named the same